# Common runtime for different DLLs

Tags: windows, dll, runtime, msvcrt

I need to build a DLL capable to load other DLLs at runtime; these other DLLs have a rather intimate relationship with the main DLL (this is Python and extensions), so they must have a common runtime. The main DLL *must* be a single file that can be simply copied on the target machine. The auxiliary DLLs will be placed in a different directory.

So: "common runtime" means no static linking; "single file + simple copy" rules out the shared MS redistributables, especially when coupled with "different directories".

I only see the following options: link all DLLs against `msvcrt.dll`; embed current `msvcrtXX` into the main DLL and re-export all its symbols; use the `msvcrtXX` of the host application. To me the first looks the simplest, because it's a common need and there are many web pages explaining how to go about it. How would you approach this?

Comment: You are asking for a pony.  The single file requirement is met by most small apps that need to deploy multiple files, it is called setup.exe

Comment: Why do you need all DLLs to use the same runtime? If that is so then the design of the DLLs was done wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Perhaps, but I cannot do much about it; these are not my DLLs and although I have source files, I certainly don't want to rewrite them. And, I my opinion what's wrong here is the One Microsoft Way of dealing with C runtimes :) E.g. on Mac OS X I compile the same libraries against a shared C runtime without any hassle.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unfortunately, I cannot use an `.exe`; I would love to. The host app expects its plug-ins to be single-file DLLs.

Comment: That's an unrelated requirement.  A setup.exe file is only used to get the files copied in the right place.  So having it copy two DLLs is certainly not a problem.

Comment: @HansPassant: Unfortunately, it is related; the host app is a client-server app and in certain scenarios it installs the plug-ins to client machines from the server, and the only way it does this is that *it copies the plug-in DLL to the plug-ins directory*.

Comment: My experiences with Python have not forced me to link to the same C runtime as Python. Are you sure you have got the design right?

Comment: I embed the whole Python into my DLL and my concern is using this DLL with standalone Python extensions, e.g. `ctypes`. My understanding is that Python and its extensions must share the same runtime; I admit I took it for granted from anecdotal evidence, but since you ask... Here's an example: [PyFile_AsFile](http://docs.python.org/c-api/file.html#PyFile_AsFile) returns a `FILE*` and AFAIK it wouldn't work if runtimes are different, would it?

Comment: What runtime does the host app use?  If you link against that, it will already be in memory when your DLLs are loaded.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: It's `msvcrt90` now; a version ago it was `msvcrt80`. I leave this option as a last resort. I wonder if anybody tried the second way: embedding the whole `msvcrt`.

Comment: @MikhailEdoshin: at the risk of the moderator's displeasure, I'll point out that you might want to seek legal advice about that option.

Comment: So, the main DLL is a plug-in and is copied to the plug-in directory by the host application.  How do the Python extensions (the subsidiary DLLs) get onto the machine?

Comment: @Harry Johnson: Some of them are zipped to the DLL and are unzipped during installation; some are expected to be downloaded later. Well, technically I can unzip them plus common `msvcrtXX` into the same directory, but I do not want to pollute it; it's not my plug-in directory, after all. If I could put them all into a subdirectory at least... But, AFAIK, I can't; I can put `msvcrtXX` there, but all DLLs will have to stay together, right? (P.S. If MS *forbids* embedding legally this is just... great.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you re-architecture so that your plug-in DLL (the one the host application loads explicitly) contains nothing but proxy functions plus the file management logic.  This DLL could use a static runtime, or no runtime at all.

Put the actual functionality (and in particular all code that needs to share a runtime with the Python extensions) in a separate ("primary") DLL and put this DLL, as well as the runtime of your choice, in the same directory as the Python extensions.

The primary DLL and the runtime could be zipped to the plug-in DLL, along with the core extensions.  (I *presume* this is within the scope of the runtime's redistributable license, since it's basically the same as the way most installers work, but you should check for yourself.)

The calls to the plug-in will be slightly less efficient since they have to go through the proxy DLL, but the performance difference probably won't be measurable. :-)

Comment: PS: I do not know whether MS forbids embedding of the runtime in the way you describe, but as I've never heard of anyone doing it some caution may be advisable.  I have some doubts about its technical feasibility as well, but they might not be well-founded.

Comment: Well, this is a good piece of advice, thank you very much! I'll have to just write the unzip code (so far I was lazy enough to simply reuse Python `zipfile` for this). And I'll check the MS license too. Thanks!

Comment: They don't forbid statically linking to the CRT, legally or otherwise. In fact, it's an explicit option configurable in Visual Studio. But that doesn't make it a good idea... I don't understand how "embedding the runtime" is any different from "static linking".

Comment: @CodyGray: if I've understood correctly, by "embedding the runtime" the OP meant statically linking to the CRT in one DLL, but also exporting the CRT functions/symbols from that DLL for the other DLLs to use.  (But he seems to be happy with my alternative suggestion so the issue is probably moot.)

Comment: Yes, by "embedding" I meant that I'll compile the runtime as if it was going to be a shared library, but without final linking, and then link all its objects together with mine into my DLL. I've asked about this on MSDN forums, but the answer was, of course, "not supported" :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option (in my humble opinion, much better) would be to dynamically link - aka. LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress) the dependencies when the main starts. This would allow you to support cases of missing DLLs and/or support your own internal version scheme.

Comment: I don't think I can deal with *runtime* issues this way: I have to link the runtime library at compile time.

Comment: Sorry, the C-Runtime! Yes of course, I oversaw this. I thought you wanted to build your "own" common set of libraries.